# How does PHP function dependancy work?

Tags: php, laravel, function, dependency-injection

I have an example here from the framework Laravel.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input("name");
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is that Request is explicitly defined within the function signature of `store()`.

Couldn't php's type inference figure out what is being passed into the function?

Would this even be considered dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, you are simply stating what data type you accept into the function. The class/function has no knowledge of how to instantiate/create that object. If you want to abstract further then use generic 'interfaces when setting up what is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is method level dependency injection. The `Request` is being passed into the `store` method, instead of the `store` method knowing how to create the `Request` object.

The type hint in the method signature does two things.

First, for plain PHP, it enforces the fact that the parameter passed to the `store` method must be a `Request` object, or an object that inherits from `Request`. If you attempt to call the `store()` method with anything other than a `Request` object (or descendant), you will get an error.

Because of this strict type enforcement, we know that the `$request` parameter must be a `Request` object (or descendant), and we can depend on its public interface being available for use (you know the `input()` method will exist).

Second, for Laravel, it tells the Laravel container what type of object this method needs, so that the correct object can be resolved out of the container and passed to the method. Laravel's controller methods are called through the container, which allows automatic dependency resolution of method calls.

If you were to remove the type hint, this would cause two issues. At an abstract level, it would allow you to pass any type of object, or even scalar values, to the `store()` method. If you attempt to call `input()` on a string, you're going to have problems. At a more concrete level, this will break Laravel's automatic dependency resolution of controller methods. Without the type hint, Laravel can't know what object the method requires, so it won't pass in anything, so in reality you'd get an error saying that you can't call `input()` on `null` (or an error saying the store method requires one parameter; not sure, didn't test).